# Save In-app Billing subscription status in Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-billing

So, in-app billing docs suggest to save subscription status and expiration date on your server and make a validation call to Google Play only near subscription expires.

I was wondering, how could I validate something like this, before saving to Firebase Database, so not just any user could save this status and date in the database?

As far as I know you can only integrate Google Play app to Firebase for Analytic purpose. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a complete answer, but I'm trying to figure this out, too. I think what you want to do is use the authentication service that Firebase offers (i.e. Firebase isn't just analytics). That way, users recorded there can be checked against data from your app's implementation of in-app billing.

1. Have users sign in/create an account via Firebase. [Tutorial](https://howtofirebase.com/firebase-authentication-for-web-d58aad62cf6d)
2. Have your app use that UID to check against Firebase's auth info in the server. (This is where I'm stuck.)

The whole "generate payload" question doesn't seem to have clear examples for non-consumable items. Keep in mind that some extra process may be necessary to make this a secure transaction, but using servers seems to be considered a good first step.

Edit: there's also [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens):

> "Note: Many use cases for verifying ID tokens on the server can be
>   accomplished by using Security Rules for the Firebase Realtime
>   Database and Cloud Storage. See if those solve your problem before
>   verifying ID tokens yourself."